# Los hilos en java

Tags: java

Hice una practica de un curso que estoy tomando por Internet que es sobre hilos y tiene que imprimir la palabra "-G-E-E-K-"

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero lo que no comprendo es que si se están ejecutando todos los hilos simultáneamente porque la palabra sale en orden?. No debería de combinarse las letras?. Como por ejemplo "-E-K-E-G-" Ó " -G-E-K-E"?

Se que para eso se utiliza el método sleep(); pero de todas formas debería de suceder lo mismo, o no?

Muchas gracias.

Este es mi codigo:

```
Clase Main

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         G hilo0 = new G();
        E1 hilo1 = new E1();
        E2 hilo2 = new E2();
         K hilo3 = new K();



         hilo0.start();

         try{
             //se que aquí se coloca un sleep para que todos se detengan por 
             //un momento
             //y posteriormente volverse a ejecutar
             //pero que no deberia de ejecutarse cualquier clase al momento
            //de volverse a compilar? (cuando se acabe el sleep)
             hilo0.sleep(20);

         }catch(InterruptedException e){
              System.out.println(" Error en la clase " + e);

         }

         hilo1.start();

         try{
             hilo1.sleep(20);

         }catch(InterruptedException e){
              System.out.println(" Error en la clase " + e);

         }

         hilo2.start();

         try{
             hilo2.sleep(20);

         }catch(InterruptedException e){
              System.out.println(" Error en la clase " + e);

         }


         hilo3.start();
         try{
            hilo3.sleep(20);

         }catch(InterruptedException e){
             System.out.println(" Error en la clase " + e);

         }

    }
}
```

(Estas son otras clases)

```
public class G extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {

            System.out.print("-G");
            System.out.print("-");

            try {

                G.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en el hilo " + e);

            }

        }


    }
}


public class E1 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("E");
            System.out.print("-");

            try {

                E1.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                System.out.println("Error en el hilo " + e);

            }

        }

    }
}

public class E2 extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("E");
            System.out.print("-");

            try {

                E2.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en el hilo " + e);

            }

        }

    }
}

public class K extends Thread {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            System.out.print("k");
            System.out.print("-");
            System.out.println("");
            try {

                K.sleep(1000);

            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Error en el hilo " + e);

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pues porque estás lanzando los threads de uno en uno y esperando 20 milisegundos desde que lanzas uno hasta que lanzas el siguiente.

Lanzas el primero, que escribe la G y se duerme 1 segundo. En tu thread principal continuas la ejecución, y esperas 20 milisegundos, con lo que terminas el sleep antes que el thread.

Entonces lanzas el segundo thread que hace lo mismo: escribe su letra y se duerme 1 segundo. Tu thread principal sigue, espera sus 20 milisegundos y lanza el siguiente...

Y así con todos.

Cada thread no se lanza cuando creas el objeto, sino cuando ejecutas el start.

Comment: Gracias. No había entendido el funcionamiento del método sleep();